# How do I simplify the union and intersection of sets.

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

In a solution to a homework problem, it says that $P((A\cup B)\cap C')=P(A\cup B\cup C)-P(C)$. I couldn't figure out how these two are equivalent. I have tried distributing $C$ into $(A\cup B)$ but I do not see where the $-P(C)$ comes from. Could someone explain what is happening here?

Comment: Let $X=A\cup B$. Then the problem simplifies to $P(X\cap C')=P(X\cup C)-P(C')$. This is fairly easy to see if you draw some Venn diagrams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to condition after shampooing.
$$\begin{align}
P((A\cup B)\cap C') &= P(C' | A\cup B) \cdot P(A\cup B) \\
                    &= [1-P(C|A\cup B)]\cdot P(A\cup B) \\
                    &= P(A\cup B) - P(C \cap (A\cup B)) \\
&= P(A\cup B) - [P(C) + P(A\cup B) -P(C\cup A \cup B)] \\
&= P(A\cup B \cup C) - P(C).
\end{align}$$